# Sony smart TV Bravia kdl-48w600b Developer Mode?

Tags: sony

How do I turn on "developer mode" on Sony Bravia kdl-48w600b? I can't find anything in preferences that will take me to debug mode. Where are the hidden options, such as "about" and "build" like in other Sony Bravia TV models. There must be a way to activate "developer mode" in this TV? Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is off-topic for StackOverflow, but I'm not 100% sure where it *would* be on-topic. SuperUser is pretty much the catch-all so I've suggested there. Not sure why this question is getting downvotes though - it's perfectly coherent, just not on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no Developer Mode on Sony Bravia, that you can switch on by yourself ( only by contacting Sony managers).

But, you can use URL LOADER from Opera Store to test your app on this platform.

You can read more about it here - dev.opera.com/tv/testing-your-app-inside-opera-tv-store